# Jersey Exception

Tags: java, jersey

Does anyone know what this exception means? I'm using GWT - Java 1.7.

Here the console output:

```
[WARN] failed jersey-servlet
javax.servlet.ServletException: com.sun.jersey.spi.inject.Errors$ErrorMessagesException
at org.mortbay.jetty.servlet.ServletHolder.initServlet(ServletHolder.java:437)
at org.mortbay.jetty.servlet.ServletHolder.doStart(ServletHolder.java:256)
...
```

Here's the web.xml:

```xml
<servlet>
  <servlet-name>jersey-servlet</servlet-name>
  <servlet-class>com.sun.jersey.spi.container.servlet.ServletContainer</servlet-class>
  <init-param>
     <param-name>com.sun.jersey.config.property.packages</param-name>
     <param-value>de.mme2app.open.server, org.codehaus.jackson.jaxrs</param-value>
  </init-param>
  <init-param>
     <param-name>com.sun.jersey.api.json.POJOMappingFeature</param-name>
     <param-value>true</param-value>
  </init-param>
  <load-on-startup>1</load-on-startup>
</servlet>

<servlet-mapping>
  <servlet-name>jersey-servlet</servlet-name>
  <url-pattern>/rest/*</url-pattern>
</servlet-mapping>
```

Comment: IIRC the `com.sun.jersey.config.property.packages` param should point to packages containing your resources and providers - why is `org.codehaus.jackson.jaxrs` in there?

Comment: because we are using jax-rs in our project, is it wrong there?

Comment: Yeah, that doesn't make sense. Try removing it, like in my answer.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I haven't verified that this is causing that error specifically, but the `com.sun.jersey.config.property.packages` param should just point to packages containing your resources and providers. It doesn't seem like `org.codehaus.jackson.jaxrs` belongs there. Try it will just:

```xml
<init-param>
    <param-name>com.sun.jersey.config.property.packages</param-name>
    <param-value>de.mme2app.open.server</param-value>
</init-param>
```

Assuming `de.mme2app.open.server` is the package in your project with resources/providers.